# Share Contract: How to share two different types of data from a single page?

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8.1

How can I share two or more different types of content (StorageFile and Link) from the same page using the Share Contract in a source app?

The `DataTransferManager.ShowShareUI()` triggers a single event handler that prepares the data package for sharing.

How can I create two (or more) event handlers, one of which handles images and the other one handles text, from the same page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating multiple event handlers create one [DataRequested](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.datatransfer.datatransfermanager.datarequested.aspx) handler and add multiple data objects to the same DataRequest. The target app can then choose the most appropriate data type (you cannot force the target to choose multiple types).

```
private async void DataRequested(DataTransferManager sender, DataRequestedEventArgs e)
{
    DataRequest request = e.Request;
    request.Data.Properties.Title = "Share Link or StorageFile";
    request.Data.Properties.Description = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet";

    // Share some text
    request.Data.SetText("consectetur adipiscing elit");
    // Share a link
    request.Data.SetWebLink(new Uri("http://example.com"));

    // And share a file. 
    // A deferral to find the file asynchronously. It's not needed
    // if the file is already cached in a variable
    DataRequestDeferral deferral = request.GetDeferral();
    try
    {
        StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///assets/logo.png"));
        List<IStorageItem> items = new List<IStorageItem>();
        items.Add(file);
        request.Data.SetStorageItems(items);
    }
    finally
    {
        deferral.Complete();
    }
}
```

Comment: If I share a text, a weblink and an image (StorageFile) to Facebook in a single data package. How would the target application behave? Which content will it choose? To me, this looks like an API limitation; why can't I share text and images separately and not be dependent on the target app's behavior?

Comment: It's up to the target how to behave. The guideline is for all of the items in the package to be different representations of the same data and for the share target to select the richest available data type that it supports. If you want to share separately you'd have to share twice, or if you want to include both in the same data you can share HTML. There's no way to avoid a dependency on the target app's behavior since the target app has to know what to do with the shared data to do something with it.